# hwmon "refresh rate"? how often are sensors read?

Tags: monitoring

I'm trying to understand how often hwmon attributes/sensors are read/updated. A hwmon driver can have the `HWMON_C_UPDATE_INTERVAL` attribute, but it looks like that is just a way to expose the update interval to the user, and the hwmon driver must read it and react appropriately.

Many hwmon drivers, e.g., nvme at drivers/nvme/host/hwmon.c, do not have such an attribute. They provide a read callback to get various sensor values. Does the hwmon system have a rate at which it calls every read callback for every sensor/attribute?

Or am I missing the bigger picture and the read actually happens when the sysfs entry is read, and otherwise actually not read at all?